# Difference beetween chttpd and httpd in CouchDB configuration

Tags: couchdb

I`m new with couchdb and I was configuring it for a new project, I had a doubt about what is the difference beetween httpd and chttpd in couch db main config:

[image]

vs:

[image]

when do you use one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation regarding [chttpd](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#chttpd)

> In CouchDB 2.x, the chttpd section refers to the standard, clustered
> port. All use of CouchDB, aside from a few specific maintenance tasks
> as described in this documentation, should be performed over this
> port.

`chttpd` essentially is for address and port bindings.

[httpd](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#httpd) on the other hand is for configuring behaviors over a connection (i.e. `chttpd`), for example, to configure [CORS](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#httpd/enable_cors).